# Issue sorting inside while loop

Tags: php, sorting

I have a strange issue happening. I've got a table where I want to order the number of times a product was sold. I'll post the query, but the issue is inside the while loop.

Query:

```
$cat = $db->query("SELECT *, COUNT(id_produto) as quantos FROM produtos p JOIN pedidos m ON p.id_prod = m.id_produto GROUP BY id_produto ORDER BY quantos +0 DESC");
$cat->execute();
```

Now the loop:

```
while($res_cat = $cat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$quantidade_ok = $res_cat['quantos'] * $res_cat['qtde'];
$quanti = array($quantidade_ok);
rsort($quanti);
foreach($quanti as $ord){
echo $ord."<br>";
}
```

The output is:
40
50
4
1
3
2
10

But I want it to be:
50
40
10
4
3
2
1

I'll be happy for any help.

Comment: It looks like you use foreach loop inside while loop ?

Comment: I have to sort it inside the while loop. Is there another way I should do it?

Comment: What is the output of `$quanti` after complete the while loop? Give me the output of `print_r($quanti)` after finishing while loop.

Comment: Array ( [0] => 40 ) 50
Array ( [0] => 50 ) 4
Array ( [0] => 4 ) 1
Array ( [0] => 1 ) 3
Array ( [0] => 3 ) 2
Array ( [0] => 2 ) 10
Array ( [0] => 10 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sorting within a loop (so your sorting already happened), and you're sorting an array with just 1 value `$quanti`, so your sort does nothing.

You have 2 ways to approach this properly: edit your query to actually sort how you wish, or sort the PHP array before looping it.

### Option 1: Edit your query

Based on your code it seems clear that you wish to sort by the product of `quantos` times `qtde`. So you can simply edit your query as follows:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(id_produto) as quantos 
FROM produtos p JOIN pedidos m ON p.id_prod = m.id_produto 
GROUP BY id_produto 
ORDER BY (quantos*qtde) DESC
```

### Option 2: Sort via PHP

If you prefer to sort via `PHP` as you don't want to change your query, you can simply populate a temporary array, the product of `quantos` times `qtde` as key and then use `krsort` to sort the array.

In code:

```
$array = [];
while ($res_cat = $cat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $key = $res_cat['quantos'] * $res_cat['qtde'];
    $array[$key] = $res_cat;
}
krsort($array);
foreach ($array as $ord => $res_cat) {
    echo $ord."<br>";
}
```

Comment: The query solution looks nice too. But how would I output (quantos*qtde) inside my table?

Comment: You can add it as an additional field`, (quantos*qtde) as resulting_product`

Comment: So sorry, but I didn't understand this

Comment: The query sort worked for me too. This is how it looks like now:
   $cat = $db->prepare("SELECT *, COUNT(id_produto) as quantos,   COUNT(id_produto)*qtde as quantos_sim FROM produtos p JOIN pedidos m ON p.id_prod = m.id_produto GROUP BY id_produto ORDER BY quantos_sim DESC");
Thanks, @Andrea Olivato!

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite $quanti each time so it always has a single value.

Try this:

```
$quanti = [];
while($res_cat = $cat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $quantidade_ok = $res_cat['quantos'] * $res_cat['qtde'];
    $quanti[] = $quantidade_ok;
}

rsort($quanti);

foreach($quanti as $ord){
    echo $ord."<br>";
}
```